# Probability of finding a block

Tags: mining, difficulty

Today I learned that for Bitcoin, the probability of a hash being valid is approximately `1/(D*2^32)`, whereas D denotes to the difficulty. Is this also true for Ethereum, or in general for other cryptocurrencies? If not, what would be the equivalent for Ethereum?